# Issue plotting line graph with categorical data on the x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following code, where I am trying to plot a line graph with numeric values on the Y-axis and a cateogrical x-axis (3 categories: never, former, current).

However, it keeps giving me the error: 'str' object has no attribute 'view'.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
fig.tight_layout(pad=3.2)
 
newdata = newdf.groupby('smoking-number').mean().reset_index()
sem = newdf.groupby('smoking-number').sem().reset_index()
newdata['smoking-number'] = newdata['smoking-number'].map({1: 'never', 2: 'former', 3: 'current'})
newdata.plot.line(x='smoking-number',y='distance', yerr= sem, ax=axes[0],legend=False)
newdata.plot.line(x='smoking-number',y='duration', yerr= sem, ax=axes[1],legend=False)
upperbounddistance = max(newdata[['distance']].values)+max(sem[['distance']].values)
lowerbounddistance = min(newdata[['distance']].values)-min(sem[['distance']].values)
upperboundduration = max(newdata[['duration']].values)+max(sem[['duration']].values)
lowerboundduration = min(newdata[['duration']].values)-min(sem[['duration']].values)
axes[0].set_ylim(lowerbounddistance,upperbounddistance)
axes[0].set_xlim(0.5,3.5)
axes[1].set_ylim(lowerboundduration,upperboundduration)
axes[1].set_xlim(0.5,3.5)
axes[0].set_ylabel("Wayfinding distance")
axes[0].set_xlabel("Smoking frequency")
axes[1].set_ylabel("Wayfinding duration")
axes[1].set_xlabel("Smoking frequency")
```

I would be so grateful if anybody would be able to give me a helping hand?

First 10 lines of newdf 'smoking-number column', 'duration' and 'distance columns':

```
distance
10  48.146090
13  98.877301
17  66.670310
19  95.764316
21  78.737108
22  48.404197
25  63.910073
27  40.862231
28  50.223985
30  38.724922

duration
10  40.976006
13  90.093298
17  88.349603
19  82.737323
21  72.579054
22  40.059987
25  57.629693
27  38.419589
28  40.834470
30  34.813547

smoking-number
10  1.0
13  1.0
17  1.0
19  1.0
21  1.0
22  1.0
25  3.0
27  1.0
28  1.0
30  1.0
```

Comment: Is there something in the debugger message that points at the line that resulted in the error?

Comment: The issue was pointing to this line: newdata.plot.line(x='smoking-number',y='distance', yerr= sem, ax=axes[0],legend=False)

Comment: Hi, with the sample data you provided, your code works fine.